# Resources from appcompat-v7:22.2.0 giving error in Android Studio

Tags: android-layout

I have added  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0' as dependency in build.gradle. But then also app giving error in accessing many resources from appcompat-v7.

Error:

`Error:(25, 64) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').`

Comment: Please help!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

please provide the detail error stack-trace

In Build.gradle add this in dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```